# list to custom dictionary one liner

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list:

```
a = [0,1,2,5]
```

I want to get output something similar to:

```
output = [{'i':0,'v':0},{'i':1,'v':0},{'i':2,'v':0},{'i':5,'v':0}]
```

with one line of code/expression where:

```
output[indx]['i'] = a[indx]
```

and:

```
output[indx]['v'] = 0
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: Please don't accept pointless edits - note that [two reviewers correctly rejected it](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12967219).

Answer (score 2):

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehension) to produce your output list:

```
[{'i': i, 'v': 0} for i in a]
```

This produces a list with the same number of elements as `a` has, each a dictionary wit hthe `'i'` value set to an element from `a`:

```
>>> a = [0, 1, 2, 5]
>>> [{'i': i, 'v': 0} for i in a]
[{'v': 0, 'i': 0}, {'v': 0, 'i': 1}, {'v': 0, 'i': 2}, {'v': 0, 'i': 5}]
```